# Value arriving late? “Value below was evaluated just now”

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, axios

```
let currComp = this;
let projects = []
let dataArr = []    


async function getData() {
  let getProject =
    await axios.get('url', {
      auth: {
        username: 'username',
        password: 'pw'
      }
    })

  let projects = await getProject.data.value;
  let arr = []
  let KPIs = []

  projects.map(project => {
    let item = () => axios.get(`url`, {
      auth: {
        username: 'username',
        password: 'pw'
      }
    })

    arr.push(item)
    console.log('arr', arr)
  })

  let results = await axios.all(arr)

  results.map(result => {

    result().then(function(v) {
      KPIs.push(v.data.value)
    })
  })

}

getData();
```

What I am trying to do is:

1. get an axios call to fetch the name of the projects.
2. Use those fetched names to call multiple axios calls. This is supposed to give me some data from that project.
3. `results = await axios.all(arr)` contains functions that gives me the responses to the API call.
4. The responses gets pushed in the the array `KPIs`.
5. When I try to `console.log('KPIs', KPIs)` at the end, it gives me

[image]

which seems to be an empty array, but when I open it,

[image]

it actually has the value that I want.

The problem is, when I try to use this array in my code, it only gives me the first item of the array.

I tried to search this issue online, and it only told me that the value is arriving late.

I want to use the full array with the full result.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Why are you creating that array of functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `results = await axios.all(arr)` contains functions that gives me the responses to the API call.

Yes, but that's pointless. You don't want functions that return promises for responses, and  there's no use to call `axios.all` on array of functions or await that.

You will instead need to build an array of promises, and `all()` and `await` *that*.

You shouldn't need to use `then` either. You can simplify your code a lot:

```
async function getData() {
  const getProject = await axios.get('url', {
    auth: {
      username: 'username',
      password: 'pw'
    }
  });

  const projects = getProject.data.value;
  const promises = projects.map(project =>
    axios.get(`url`, {
      auth: {
        username: 'username',
        password: 'pw'
      }
    })
  );

  const results = await axios.all(promises)

  const KPIs = results.map(v => v.data.value);
}
```

Comment: It seems like it's working! One thing is that when I do the second axios call, there are some APIs that won't work because the data does not exist in that project. This was intended. But I want it to skip that whenever it doesn't exist and only call it from the one that exists. How can I do that?

Comment: You can filter the `projects` (before doing the call) or the `results`