# React ref returns null with info "value below was evaluated just now"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get ref of the Carousel  but in componentDidMount value of the this.carousel always returns null with info that "value below was evaluated just now". So, I dont understand in what time this value can be calculated and how I can get value of the current not to be null.

I have read answers on this questions but unfortunately they didnt help to understand what am I doing wrong (or examples didnt work for me)

[React antd carousel methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56935749/react-antd-carousel-methods/56936039?noredirect=1#comment100413369_56936039)

[Value arriving late? “Value below was evaluated just now”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52007379/value-arriving-late-value-below-was-evaluated-just-now)

```
export default class ImagePreviewCarousel extends React.Component<any, any> {

    carousel = React.createRef();

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.carousel);
        console.log(this.carousel.current);
    }

    render() {
        const { url, imgList } = this.props;
        const orderLayout = document.getElementById('order-layout');
        const applicationLayout = document.getElementById('application');

        return (
            createPortal(<ImageViewer url={url} onRef={this.carousel} onClose={this.props.onClose} imgList={imgList} />, orderLayout || applicationLayout)
        )
    }
}

const ImageViewer = (props: any) => {
    console.log(props.onRef);
    return (
        <Modal 
            footer={null} 
            visible={props.onClose} 
            onCancel={props.onClose}
            bodyStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#000' }}
            width={'800px'}
        >
            <div style={{
                display: 'flex', 
                flexDirection: 'column', 
                justifyContent: 'center', 
                marginTop: 'auto', 
                marginBottom: 'auto', 
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%', 
                zIndex: 10
            }}>
                <Carousel ref={props.onRef}>
                    {props.imgList}
                </Carousel>
            </div>
        </Modal>
    );
}
```

P.S react version is 16.4.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React antd carousel methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56935749/react-antd-carousel-methods)

Answer (score 0):

The ImageViewer can be wrapped by `forwardRef`, please check the details.

https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-to-dom-components

Hopefully, it helps you :)